# How to decide to convert to categorical variable or keep it numeric?

Tags: algorithm, data-science, categorical-data

This might be a basic or trivial question and might be straightforward. Still I would like to ask this to clear my doubt once and for all.

Take example of Passanger Class in Famous Titanic Data. Functionally it is indeed a Categorical Data, so it will make perfect sense to convert it to categorical variable. Algorithms as per my understanding tend to see a pattern specific to that class. But at the same time if you see it as numeric variable, it might denote a range also for a decision tree. Say passangers in between first class and second class.

It looks both are correct and both will affect the machine learning algorithm outputs in different ways.

Which one is appropriate and is there anywhere there is a extensive discussion about it? Should we use such ambiguous variables as numeric as well its copy as a categorical variable, which might prove to be a technique to uncover more patterns?

Comment: The question I always wonder to determine if I consider a variable numeric or factor is: it makes sense to consider intermediate values between those presented in the data set? That is, it makes sense for you to consider the class 1.3? If the answer is yes, then consider it as numerica, if not, as factor.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose it's up to you whether you'd rather interpret a continuous `PassengerClass` variable as "for every one-unit increase in `PassengerClass`, the passenger's likelihood of survival goes up/down X%," versus a categorical (factor) `PassengerClass` as, "the likelihoods of survival for groups 2 and 3 (for example, leaving 1st-class passengers as the base group) are X and Y% percent higher, respectively, than the base group, holding all else constant."

I think about variables like `PassengerClass` almost as "treatment groups." Yes, I suppose you could interpret it as continuous, but I think it makes more sense to consider the unique effects of each class like "people who were given the drug versus those who weren't" - you can very easily compare the impacts of being in a higher class (e.g. 2 or 3) to being in the most common class, 1, which again would be left out.

Comment: I completely agree with this answer. A big reason data scientists are so in demand is the fact that real world analysis requires constantly making this kind of judgement call.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with mapping categorical notions to numerical is that some algorithms (e.g. neural networks) will interpret the value itself as having a meaning, i.e. you would get different results if you assign values 1,2,3 to passenger classes than, for example 0,1,2 or 3,2,1. The correspondence between the passenger classes and numbers is purely conventional and doesn't necessarily convey any additional meaning.

One could argue that the lesser the number, the "better" the class is, however it's still hard to interpret it as "the first class is twice as good as second class", unless you'll define some measure of "goodness" that will make the relation between numbers "1" and "2" sensible.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, you have categorical data that is ordinal - meaning you can rank the categories (from best accommodations to worst, for example) but they're still categories. Regardless of how you label them, there's no actual information about the relative distances among your categories. You can put them in a table, but not (correctly) on a number line. In cases like this, it's generally best to treat your categorical data as independent categories.